# how to use maven command to deploy war package to local tomcat

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

How can I use maven to deploy war package to local tomcat?
like: **mvn deploy -file:C\tomcat\webapp**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache Tomcat Maven Plugin](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/)